# Split a number into random non-zero numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

I have some pairs of numbers, let's say

```
[X1,Y1], [X2,Y2] ..... [Xn,Yn]    Y > X
```

I have a another number, say Z. Now what I want is to split Z into random values Nm such that it always meets following condition:

```
N1 + N2 + N3 ...... Nn = Z
Nm > 0
Nm <=  Ym - Xm
```

Comment: Where do `X1`, `Y1`, etc. come into this?  Did you perhaps want `Xm <= Nm <= Ym` for all `m`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson : corrected the constraint

Comment: What if X1>Z? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF the series y_1 - x_1 + … + y_m - x_m < z OR x_i ≥ y_i for any i
  FAIL
ELSE DO
  residual := z
  FOR i := 1 to m-1
    n_i := (y_i - x_i) × random (0,1]
    residual := residual - n_i
    IF residual ≤ 0
      BREAK
  n_m := residual 
WHILE n_m ≤ 0 OR n_m > y_m-x_m
```

Every n_i before n_m falls into the range because it is the upper bound times a random number between 0 and 1.  The last value falls into the range because, if it did not, we would have looped and tried again.  The numbers add up to z because n_m is the difference of z and the sum of the rest of the series.

Answer (score 0):

You have M intervals [ Xi, Yi ] and you want a random number in each interval so that the sum of all numbers is Z.

The sum of such numbers must needs be between SUM(Xi) and SUM(Yi). So we calculate both:

```
Zmin = 0;
Zmax = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    Zmin += X[i];
    Zmax += Y[i];
    Z[i] = X[i];
}
```

Now we check that Z is between Zmin and Zmax. If it is not, there's no way of obtaining a Z vector that meets the constraints.

If Z is between Zmin and Zmax, we can imagine to start with a Z vector which is a copy of X, and sprinkle the difference between Z and Zmin at random among all Zi's.

```
remainder = Z - Zmin;
if ((remainder < 0) || (remainder + Zmin > Zmax)) {
    // Can't do.
}

// There are several ways of equidistributing the remainder.
// This is not one of them, but it's simple.
// If Z is very near Zmax, performances will suffer.
while (remainder > 0) {
    // Choose 
    i = rand()*m;
    // Can we increase Z[i]?
    if (Z[i] < Y[i]) {
        Z[i]++;
        remainder--;
    }
}
// DONE!
```

**A more complicated way that would run in O(n)** would be to equidistribute the remainder R among the m slots in proportion to each slot's width. On average, a slot (Y[i]-X[i]) wide should receive an extra of R*(Y[i]-X[i])/(Zmax - Zmin). We could use Bresenham's algorithm to do this as exactly as possible, but if we want to have a random distribution,  we run the risk of under-allocating the first K slots, and having such a large remainder that even if we maxed out all the remaining slots we still wouldn't exhaust it.

To avoid this, we need to keep a running total of how much we can defer to the following intervals, starting with Zmax - Zmin. So at iteration i, if the next intervals from i+1 to m can dispatch up to D, and remainder is R, whatever we add to Z[i] must leave (remainder - Z[i] + X[i] <= D), which means that  Z[i] - X[i] >= remainder - D; i.e., our random number that we add to Z[i] (currently still equal to X[i]) must start from MAX(remainder - D, 0). Ideally, this will always be 0. So we can attribute a random number from MAX(remainder-D, 0) to Y[i]-X[i]. Let this interval be of width Q. We want to assign on average `Q*remainder/(D+Q)` to this interval, and that means `Z[i] = Y[i]-X[i]-Q+rand()*(Q*remainder/(D+Q))`.

```
D = Zmax - Zmin;

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {

    V = MAX(remainder-D, 0);

    Q = (Y[i] - X[i]) - V; // This is positive, or we would have failed earlier

    Z[i] = Y[i]-X[i]-Q+rand()*(Q*remainder/(D+Q));

    remainder -= (Z[i] - X[i]);
}
```

This is a quick implementation in PHP which appears to work.

```
<?php
    $X = [ 1, 4, 11, 3, 5, 17, 22, 35, 120, 0 ];
    $Y = [ 8, 9, 33, 9, 9, 28, 24, 36, 215, 3 ];

    $m = count($X);

    $ZZ= 0;
    // Construct a Z that will work.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
        // $Y[$i] = rand($X[$i], $X[$i] + 20);
        $ZZ += rand($X[$i], $Y[$i]);
    }

    $Zmin = 0;
    $Zmax = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
        $Zmin += $X[$i];
        $Zmax += $Y[$i];
    }

    $R = $ZZ - $Zmin;
    if (($R < 0) || ($R + $Zmin > $Zmax)) {
        die("Can't do.\n");
    }

    $D = $Zmax - $Zmin;

   for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
        $A = max($R-$D, 0); // Cannot distribute less than this.
        $B = min($Y[$i]-$X[$i], $R); // Nor more than this.


        $Q = ($B - $A); // This is positive, or we would have failed earlier
        assert('$Q > 0');

        $Z[$i] = $X[$i] + rand($A, $B); // floor($A + ($B-$A)*rand());

        $R -= ($Z[$i] - $X[$i]);
        assert('$R >= 0');
        assert('$X[$i] <= $Z[$i]');
        assert('$Y[$i] >= $Z[$i]');
   }
```